# QML : what is difference between ToolButton and Button

Tags: qt, qml, desktop-application

I'm new in Desktop Application. I'm trying to create one Desktop Application.

I was gone through Documents of [QT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/) and there are two different Buttons:  **ToolButton** and **Button**.

I'm confused between these two.

What is the difference between these two and which should I use for Application?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is how they look.

The [documentation for `ToolButton`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls2-toolbutton.html) says:

> ToolButton is functionally similar to Button, but provides a look that is more suitable within a ToolBar.

The [guidelines](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtquickcontrols2-guidelines.html) page has more information about the various types of controls. For example, the [Buttons page](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtquickcontrols2-buttons.html) has these listings (amongst others):

> - Button - Push-button that can be clicked to perform a command or answer a question
> - [...]
> - ToolButton - Button with a look suitable for a ToolBar

`ToolButton` often lacks a [`background`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#background-prop) in its default state. In the screenshot below, taken from the [Gallery example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-gallery-example.html), `ToolButton` is used in the `ToolBar` for the "back" button and the "options" button. `Button` is shown in the centre, and will generally always have a background.

[image: gallery example]